# How to auto apply index policy to newly created indexes in AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, aws-elasticsearch

We push Nginx logs to AWS Elasticsearch using Filebeat and Logstash. We have created an index pattern with the name nginx-error-logs* & nginx-access-logs*. We can see in Kibana that daily new indices are being created based on the nginx log file date pattern. We created index policy and applied to existing indices but we would like to auto-apply the same ISM policy for all the newly created indices in Elasticsearch. Kindly help us to achieve this?

Is this the correct format to apply in Devtools console?

```json
PUT _template/testindex_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["*"],
  "settings": {
    "opendistro.index_state_management.policy_id": "index_lifecycle_management_policy"
  }
}
```

Or should that be applied on the filebeat or Logstash config?

Comment: The exact settings is named `index.lifecycle.name` instead of `opendistro.index_state_management.policy_id`

Comment: Hello @Val we are using AWS open distro elasticsearch. So please check and confirm if this setting applies for this scenario also?

Comment: Yes, according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service#full-comparison) (see Operational feature), ILM is also available in AWS ES

Answer (score 0):

opendistro.index_state_management.policy_id is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

> opendistro.index_state_management.policy_id is deprecated

You have to add your index pattern in `ism_template` array of the policy. Below is the example.

```
PUT _opendistro/_ism/policies/policy_name
{
  "policy": {
    "description": "Policy to manage indices",
    "default_state": "hot",
    "states" : [
      {
        "name" : "hot",
        "actions" : [
          {
            "rollover" : {
              "min_size" : "20gb",
              "min_index_age" : "2d"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ism_template": {
      "index_patterns": [
        "nginx-error-logs*",   // **sample index pattern**
        "nginx-access-logs*"
      ],
      "priority": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever new index create, the index name pattern will match to the `ism_template` and the respective policy will be applied.

If same pattern available in multiple policy the it will attach the policy who has high prority.

Comment: Thanks, Sagar Vaghela for your input. We will check this setup